# Which certificate(Class 3 or EV) should I buy,to create a company account on Hardware/Desktop developer portal of Microsoft, for uploading apps?

Tags: windows-store-apps, code-signing, windows-store, code-signing-certificate

I want to upload my desktop app to windows store.After some searching,I found  that first I'll have to test the app with windows certification kit, then create an account on hardware/desktop portal.Submit certification test results to the portal then upload the app using developer account.
Now, for creating a company account in Hardware/Desktop portal, it is asking me to buy a certificate(Class 3 or EV).EV is for LSA and UEFI. And for other services,Class 3 certificate will do.I have no idea what LSA and UEFI are,I just want to upload my app to windows desktop store.
So,which certificate should I buy class 3 or EV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code signing certificate will work well untill you'll need to sign drivers. You can get [Comodo Code Signing certificate](http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/) as cheap or certificate from [Verisign](http://www.symantec.com/code-signing/microsoft-authenticode/) if you want to sign drivers too.

Comment: So should I buy class 3 certificate as it is cheaper.

Comment: Sure, however somewhere at microsoft website you can get a promo code and verisign certificate will cost you $99 (I use it). However I forgot where it was.

Comment: Starting from Windows 10 build 1607, only EV-signed drivers will work. [source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2016/07/26/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/)